# Как правильно понимать приватные свойства в ООП?

Tags: javascript, ооп

Куда сохраняются приватные свойства созданного объекта? Например у нас есть такой код:

```js
function User() {
  var firstName, surname;

  this.setFirstName = function(firstNameUser) {
    firstName = firstNameUser;
  }

  this.setSurname = function(surnameUser) {
    surname = surnameUser;
  }

  this.getFullName = function() {
    return surname + ' ' + firstName;
  }

}

var user1 = new User();
user1.setFirstName('Phillip');
user1.setSurname('Moore');

console.log(user1)
console.log(window.surname)
```

Мы создаем приватные свойства `firstName` и `surname`, но после создания нового объекта через конструктор, этих свойств нет в этом объекте. И в глобальной области видимости этих свойств тоже нет, куда они тогда сохраняются?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Они хранятся в замыкании. Вот более просто пример этого механизма

```
function setSecret(secret) {
    const mySecret = `My secret: ${secret}`;

    return function getSecret() {
        return mySecret;
    }
}

const secret1 = setSecret('secret 1');
const secret2 = setSecret('secret 2');

secret1(); // secret 1
secret2(); // secret 2
```

В данном случае, при каждом вызове функции `setSecret`, создается локальная область видимости ( `об А` ), где хранится одна переменная `mySecret`. В обычном случае после выполнения функции, `об А` бы уничтожилась и переменная пропала, НО мы возвращаем функцию, которая имеет доступ к созданной `об А`, поэтому `об А` сохраняется.

В вашем случае механизм тот же: функция возвращает объект, у которого есть методы, использующие область видимости этой функции.

Comment: я не понял что такое об А?

Comment: @Избытоксусликов `область видимости А`

Comment: понял спасибо большое